# transferring grooving script result into test cases

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am fetching data from one tag lets say 111 22222 and splitting by using space
like 111 and 22222.

I want to transfer the value to two different tags into different request
lets say

111 for Tag1 and 22222 for Tag2

Comment: please show your xml data.

Comment: Thanks it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Tanveer as per your comment on Ross's Answer here is the solution

you have fetch Response as 111 222

```
log.info Response  // 111 222
String [] s = s.split(" ") 
log.info s[0] //111 
log.info s[1] //222
```

Save the value in testCase Properties in groovy script

```
 testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("tagone",s[0])
 testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("tagtwo",s[1])
```

In another testStep request where you want to use this

```
<xmltag1>${#TestCase#tagone}</xmltag1>
<xmltag1>${#TestCase#tagtwo}</xmltag1>
```

So we stored property at TestCase level and used it in another step of the same Testcase

If you want the property to be used in another test case you may store at TestSuite Level

```
 testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue("tagone",s[0])
```

Comment: *I am using groovy script to run two soap request multiple times
Let's say i have two requests,Request 1 and Request 2
I want request 1 will run continuously three times and then moved to  request 2
i am using following code* 


    **enter code here**

for(int i =1;i<=9;i++)

{

if(i<=7)

{

testRunner.gotoStepByName("one")

}

else
{
testRunner.gotoStepByName("two")
}
}

//After running the above the code only request 2 is working

Comment: @TanveerSingh instead of gotoStepByName use testrunner.runteststepbyname, this will not send the control , check out this for more information https://www.soapui.org/docs/functional-testing/controlling-flow.html

Answer (score 0):

if you have the two different values assigned to variables already you can do something like the following

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)

//get field value from first test step response
def tagOne = 111
def tagTwo = 22222

//Define request you would like to add data to
def holderRequestOne = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("RequestOneName#Request")
def holderRequestTwo = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("RequestTwoame#Request")

//Find the fields in the request and set the value you would like in those fields 
holderRequestOne.setNodeValue("//XPath","$tagOne")
holderRequestTwo.setNodeValue("//XPath","$tagTwo")

//Update the requests
holderRequestOne.updateProperty()
holderRequestTwo.updateProperty()
```

This is the way I would do it using Groovy scripts. you just need to add the respected XPaths and Test Step names.

You can also do this using the property transfer test step. Which you can find more information here:

https://www.soapui.org/docs/functional-testing/properties/transferring-properties.html

A little more information on you problem, the code you have tried and you expected outcome of that code wouldn't go amiss

Comment: I wanted to fetch particular 111 222 value  by using groovy script and
splitting a value as follow:
 Step 1:Fetching a value and storing in a variable name let say "Response" 
log.info Response //output = 111 222


String []  s = s.split(" ")
log.info s[0] //111
log.info s[1] //222

Is the above way is good one to do separation ?

After that i want to send 111 and 222 in tagone and tagtwo respectively of another request